# Newbie project - start an activity from BroadcastReceive

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to build a simple daily reminder app as my first Android 
project and I'm just stucked now. Too much information from hours 
watching tutorials. :)

So I would like some help to understand the code behind 
my idea so hopefully someone explains this with ease :)

- Three times a day I want an alarm/reminder/splash to set off for ten seconds 
  with different pictures and sounds depending on the alarmtime. 
  An ability to tap/swipe to stop it before 10 seconds.

alarm1
---alarm1time08:10
---alarm1pic1.jpg
---alarm1Sound1.mp3

alarm2
---alarm2time12:30
---alarm2pic1.jpg
---alarm2Sound1.mp3

alarm3
---alarm3time18:45
---alarm3pic1.jpg
---alarm3Sound1.mp3

So how do I do this?

I'm using Android Studio 2.3 (to slow computer for 3.x...),
Java and my phones are Lollipop 5.1 API level 22 and 
Marshmallow 6.0 API level 23

This is my code that actually works without error..

But now i don't know how open an activity with my image and sounds.
I got a RED startActivity when I tried it in hRec.

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.hlm.myreminder;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int hHour1 = 08;
        int hMin1 = 10;

        Calendar hCal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        hCal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hHour1);
        hCal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, hMin1);
        hCal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Log.v("hLogging","cal set");

        Intent hIntent = new Intent(getApplication(),hRec.class);
        PendingIntent hPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,hIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Log.v("hLogging","intent set");

        AlarmManager hAlMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        hAlMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,hCal1.getTimeInMillis(),hAlMgr.INTERVAL_DAY,hPi);

        Log.v("hLogging","am set");

        // startActivity(new Intent(this, hshowreminderpic1.class)); //works
        // Log.v("hLogging","goto hshowreminderpic1 done");          //works
    }
}
```

hRec.java

```js
package com.hlm.myreminder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class hRec extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent hIntent) {

        Log.d("hLogging", "hRec:BroadcastReceiverAlarm");
        // show hshowreminderpic1

        /* startActivity gets RED */
        // startActivity(new Intent(this, hshowreminderpic1.class));

        // Log.v("hLogging","goto hshowreminderpic1 request");

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hlm.myreminder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/h_icon72"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".hshowreminderpic1"/>
        <receiver android:name=".hRec"></receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass context to start your activity from hRec.java as hRec is not an activity.
So simply write

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, hshowreminderpic1.class); 
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer but now I've got "Error:(16, 31) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(hRec,Class<hshowreminderpic1>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; hRec cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; hRec cannot be converted to Context)"

Comment: Could you try this:- Intent i = new Intent(context, hshowreminderpic1.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

Comment: Also it is not recommended to start an activity from onReceive() method because it will be jarring to the user that is looking at a screen and all of a sudden an activity pops up. The recommended method is to use the notification manager.

Comment: YES! Thank you! In fact, it is important that whatever I do, the reminder should appear. But therefore I also want to be able to finish it with a tap / slice. It's an app made for me only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(this, hshowreminderpic1.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer but now I've got "Error:(16, 31) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(hRec,Class<hshowreminderpic1>) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable (argument mismatch; hRec cannot be converted to String) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable (argument mismatch; hRec cannot be converted to Context)"

Comment: try changing `this` to `context`

Comment: Runned a few few steps longer but then: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.hlm.myreminder.hRec: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, hshowreminderpic1.class); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); context.startActivity(intent);`